# How do MOVs work for surge protection?

Tags: parallel, mov

I'm trying to understand how MOVs operate but all my online reading is calling my understanding of electronics into question.

[image]

The above diagram seems to be the typical layout of a MOV used for surge protection. When surges occur, the resistance across the MOV drops creating effectively a short.

Online resources are suggesting that this "dissipates the voltage" protecting the parallel circuit, but this doesn't make sense to me - will the protected circuit still not see the increased voltage and therefore an increased current?

My only thought is that the increased current through the MOV will cause the fuse to trip, but this isn't the mechanism of surge protection alluded to in online resources.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are not factoring is the source impedance. It won't be zero ohms and could (for a power surge) be in the region of 2 ohms (EN 61000-4-5 for example).

> *will the protected circuit still not see the increased voltage and
> therefore an increased current?*

Not when you account for the source impedance; sure there will be a moderate rise (limited by the MOV) but it won't be the full spike of voltage. Source impedance being greater than 0 ohms is the key to all shunt transient voltage suppression devices.

The fuse is there because eventually the MOV will fail and go short-circuit (usually). The fuse blows and prevents your wiring infrastructure burning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just so I understand - the high current (due to the MOV effectively shorting the circuit) through the usually negligible source resistance causes a voltage drop, protecting the protected circuit?

Comment: It doesn't really short circuit in the traditional way <-- it limits the voltage by having a much smaller impedance above a certain voltage threshold and, that much smaller impedance is much smaller than the source impedance. It acts a bit like an AC version of a Zener diode.

Comment: Something else to consider is that the major sort of overvoltage transient is a very high voltage with fast transitions and relatively short duration (microseconds). Under those conditions the inductance of the mains circuit is very significant, and the MOV is also capacitive, so that combination results in a much less damaging amount of energy seen by the protected device.

Comment: @PStechPaul not so true for localized indirect lightning strikes hence EN 61000-4-5 uses a purely resistive source impedance.

Answer (score 6):

MOVs can be found with almost any voltage rating nowadays.  But for AC circuits in the US, a [common value is 130V RMS working voltage](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=f255d04a-79a4-4f3a-b7a6-0a5fa3955849&filename=littelfuse-varistor-m3-datasheet).  What this means is that when the peak input voltage goes above \$130 * 1.414 = 183.8V\$ then the MOV will start to conduct (like a Zener diode in a DC circuit would).  As pointed out in other answers, the facility (house?) wiring provides some small impedance that allows the voltage to drop across, thus limiting the voltage at the MOV node.
As the input voltage increases more, then the MOV will conduct/turn on more.  They say "more grains will conduct".  As more grains turn on, each one being like a tiny zener diode, the device will conduct more current and dissipate more power as heat.
This process can continue over and over, for a very long time, as long as the MOV can cool down between transient events.

**Failure Mode**
During a common over voltage event (like 220VAC appearing on the 120VAC lines) as the MOV turns on, the heat tends to be highly localized inside the device, and will create hot spots.  These hot spots will eventually fail and instead of a low impedance, those spots are now high impedance, but still conducting. This creates more heat, and now a chain reaction occurs and the device catches fire in a spectacular fashion!

The fuse in your schematic is usually a "thermal" fuse.  Meaning that is is placed right next to, in contact with, the MOV, and if the MOV conducts too much current, then the fuse opens like a normal fuse would.  But also, if the MOV gets too hot it'll also open in order to [prevent the MOV from catching fire.](https://youtu.be/arN-rGcejNw?t=220)  As the video link shows, not all surge protection devices try to prevent fires.